# Docker passing environment variable

Tags: docker

Here is my DockerFile, it has a default EN, which I would like to override upon container deployment if specified.

```
ENV domain example.com

CMD ["cd","/etc/httpd/conf.d/"]
CMD [ "cp", "VirtualHost", "${domain}" ]
```

However when passing *EN* using -e command

```
docker run -it -e domain="test.com" container_id
```

I'm able to login to the container, echo $domain and it displays EV which has been passed however the copy command didn't copy the file.

Any ideas on what possibly I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two `CMD` lines, the second one will simply override the first. But in your case, I think you want to use the `WORKDIR` command to set the directory, not `CMD` e.g:

```
WORKDIR /etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

This should set the current directory for all following instructions and container start-up.

BTW I'm not sure how you're logging into this container - when you run it, the `cp` command will fire and the container will exit once it has completed. If you override the `CMD` to get a shell (for example with `docker run -it mycontainer bash`) the `cp` command will never be executed.

Comment: and the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd states `There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.` at the very beginning